# Adding an error to an attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I use

```
errors.add(:body, 'is a bit short.. ')
```

which will result in the error message

```
Body is a bit short
```

I'd like to add an error to `:body` but with the result

```
Explanation is a bit short
```

Is there a way to change beginning of the error message and still to have be attached to `:body`?

Comment: You could translate your model attribute with normal i18n. Further information can be found on the guides.rubyonrails.org site. Search there for i18n.

Comment: That seems like a hack. If your `:body` is really an `Explanation` then perhaps it should be _named_ `:explanation`.

Comment: it should, but changing a lot of the code just for a custom error seems a bit much, further more, explanation is only used here and is subject to change